# asp.net mvc 3 serverside session variable

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, session

I need a serverside session variable in asp.net MVC 3. I know it is not the best way to fix things, but we need it security wise. I need to be sure that there is a value that is not tampered with. Is there any way to set a serverside session variable that can not be deleted or changed on the client?

Comment: If you need something per user just use Session["key"] = value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `HttpContext.Current.Session`.

Comment: This creates a sessionId cookie. Is there anyway to do so without session cookie? This is because I want to set something at the very first enter of the page. This is after the user has authorized against a external (as in not .net) security provider. After that I create a cookie and I need to be sure that the cookie is not tempered with. So Therefor I want to make a hash and store that serverside and validat the cookie against the has that I have. (the hash has 2 components, both cookies, 1 provided by the security provider, 1 by myself.)

Comment: In order to keep the session in the browser over the session-less protocol you need to send something down and up: cookie, hidden field, url parameter. All of this can be tampered with. That's web development.

Comment: Just a note that this is `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session`, not `Controller.HttpContext`, so if you're accessing this within a controller, be sure to specify the right HttpContext.